# Stack Overflow and Segmentation Fault 11 in Bellman-Ford's Algorithm

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow, bellman-ford

I was implementing Bellman-Ford's Algorithm in C++ to find negative weight cycles in a currency exchange problem, and when I put a test case, it gives

`Segmentation Fault: 11`

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
struct edge
{
    int vertex;
    double weight;
};
int mindist(int A[],bool B[],int n)
{
    int v=0;
    while(B[v]==true)
        v++;
    for(int i=v;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(B[i]==false)
            if(A[i]<A[v])
                v=i;
    }
    return v;
}
class Graph
{
public:
    vector<edge> adj;

    void add(int a,int b)
    {
        edge e;
        e.vertex=a;
        e.weight=b;
        adj.push_back(e);
    }
};
int main()
{
    int n,m,u,v,j,isCycle=0;
    double w;
    edge temp;
    cin>>n>>m;
    Graph* G=new Graph[n];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        cin>>u>>v>>w;
        w=-log(w);
        G[u-1].add(v-1,w);
    }
    int* dist=new int[n];
    bool* done = new bool[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        dist[i]= 10000;
        done[i]=false;
    }
    dist[0]=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        j=mindist(dist,done,n);
        done[j]=true;
        for(int i=0;i<G[j].adj.size();i++)
        {
            temp=G[j].adj[i];
            if(dist[temp.vertex]>temp.weight+dist[j])
                dist[temp.vertex]=temp.weight+dist[j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            temp=G[i].adj[i];
            if(dist[temp.vertex]>temp.weight+dist[i])
            {
                isCycle=1;
                break;
            }
    }
    cout<<isCycle;
}
```

Test Case: (In the format:- FirstVertex SecondVertex Weight)

//Note that the following is a directed graph

```
10 9
1 2 1
6 7 1
8 9 1
9 10 1
3 4 1
7 8 1
4 5 1
5 6 1
2 3 1
```

I had initialized all the static arrays on the heap using dynamic allocation but still, I get the same error. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: `Graph* G=new Graph[n];` this creates an array of graph objects rather than intialize the vector inside the Graph class. Is this the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens when `B` is all true.

Then this loop:

```
while(B[v]==true)
    v++;
```

has undefined behaviour, and you're most likely ending up with a `v` that is "out there".
Then you return `v` to this code:

```
j=mindist(dist,done,n);
done[j]=true;
for(int i=0;i<G[j].adj.size();i++)
```

which will write somewhere in outer space and look at a `Graph` that does not exist.

Check your bounds.

Also, the use of `i` for both nested loops in that section looks fishy.
Even if it's what you intended, rename one of them so it doesn't look wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault is on line 70, so in G[i].adj[i] , adj[i] does not exists. Each of the adj[i] have size 1. Also loop on line 57 is wrong, as you have used i in nested loop as well.